# Non-empty relative current path, in standard C++?

Tags: c++, working-directory, std-filesystem

With C++17 (or Boost::filesystem), we can get the current path / current working directory using [`filesystem::current_path()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path). However - that gives us an *absolute* path.

We could also use an empty path as the relative current path - sometimes.

But - is it possible to obtain, portably, the equivalent of `"."` or `"./"` ? i.e. a non-empty relative current path?

Comment: Reading [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path), isn't `.` already supported?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Hmm. I guess it is more "supported" than I thought.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use `"."` for the current directory.

`std::filesystem` will recognize `"."` as representing the current directory / path - regardless of the platform you're on. So, it will not just happen to work on Linux/Windows, it is guaranteed to work.

```
auto relative_current path = std::filesystem::path{"."};
```

Relevant wording in the standard: [fs.path.generic.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/fs.class.path#fs.path.generic-3).

This answer is basically due to @NathanOliver...

Comment: Here is the relevant standard wording if you don't want to rely on cppreference: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/fs.class.path#fs.path.generic-3